# How to create a list of all elements present in a single cell of a dataframe?

Tags: python, list, pyspark

Let say I have a dataframe:

[image: dataframe snapshot]

now i want list of the elements present in the column `NAME`

like this:

```
['s', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'n']
```

how can we do this in pyspark?

doing this

```
LIST = df.select('NAME').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x ).collect()
 
print(LIST)
```

is yielding me

```
['s a c h i n']
```

Comment: try using splitting on spaces, this might be helpful https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/string-split-of-the-columns-in-pyspark/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just split on the space.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "s a c h i n")],["id", "name"])
df.withColumn('split_name', split('name', ' ')).show()
```

Output

```
+---+-----------+------------------+
| id|       name|        split_name|
+---+-----------+------------------+
|  1|s a c h i n|[s, a, c, h, i, n]|
+---+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: can u also please tell how to get it back to original

Comment: also how to replace a character in split_name

for eg

[sach, a, c, h, i, n]

Answer (score 0):

I belive this cover the requirements you mentioned.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split,concat_ws,regexp_replace,col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

#UDF Function for the second requirement
def custom_replace(col_values):
  first_four = col_values[:4]
  first_four = ''.join(first_four)
  col_values = col_values[1:]
  col_values.insert(0,first_four)
  return col_values

custom_replaceUDF = udf(lambda z:custom_replace(z),StringType())   

#Creating dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "s a c h i n")],["id", "name"])

#Required Transformation
df1 = df.withColumn('Splited_name', split('name', ' '))\
.withColumn('Back_to_orig_name', concat_ws(" ", "Splited_name"))\
.withColumn('reaplced_name_hard_code', regexp_replace('Back_to_orig_name', 's', 'sach'))\
.withColumn("Replaced_Name", custom_replaceUDF(col("Splited_name")))

df1.show(truncate=False)
```